# Path variable data is not recognized by spring boot when passed from angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, typescript

I have used angualr 7 and i m passing the value from the service class of angular as:

```
executeHelloWorldBeanServiceWithPathVariable(name){
    console.log("name coming from here"+name);
    return this.httpClient.get<HelloWorldBean>('http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/${name}');
     console.log("hello world bean service executed");
   }
```

The name is being printed in console as I tested:

```
console.log("name coming from here"+name);
```

Its being printed in console as here is no problem.

[image]

In my spring boot i declared as:

```
@GetMapping(path="/hello-world/path-variable/{name}")  
    public HelloWorldBean helloWorldBeanPathVariable(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        System.out.print("name is"+name);
        return new HelloWorldBean(String.format("Hello world %s", name));
    }
```

The name parameter which I pass from angular is not being printed as I tried to debug using:

```
System.out.print("name is"+name);
```

But it is showing in el expression

[image]

So in my UI I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you aren't using the actual [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax on your `executeHelloWorldBeanServiceWithPathVariable` method. I am assuming you are trying to use that because of the `${}` expression.

This might be the reason why the request didn't get parsed correctly. You should be using back ticks(`) instead of single or double quotes.

```
executeHelloWorldBeanServiceWithPathVariable(name){
  return this.httpClient.get<HelloWorldBean>(`http://localhost:8080/hello-world/path-variable/${name}`);
}
```

In addition, to actually return the observables from the API request, you will have to `subscribe()` to it on the component that requires it.

For instance,

```
constructor(
  private yourService: YourService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.yourService.executeHelloWorldBeanServiceWithPathVariable('someName').subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // do the rest here
  })
}
```

Comment: @ashwinkarki glad to help!

Answer (score -1):

use backticks ` instead using ' or " for concatanation whenever work on typescript. 
specifically where you  evaluate some value like "my string"+${myname}

Comment: this is not an answer to the question - more like a comment.